# Ajax синхронизация на устройствах

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Приветствую.

У меня есть простенький чат на ajax. Когда я ввел ник и сообщение - нажимаю кнопку отправить и значения добавляются в нужную таблицу, нужные поля и т.д. и это все происходит без перезагрузки страницы.

**Но в чем же моя проблема?**

Проблема в том, что ajax работает только на "одной" стороне постоянно, то есть на моей.

**Приведу пример:** открыл 2 браузера, зашел на нужную страничку.

С **1** браузера я отправил такие сообщения (ник и сообщение через пробел, следующее сообщение через запятую): 1 1, 2 2, 3 3. То есть 3 сообщения. Все отлично, ajax работает, в БД добавляет, все без перезагрузки, красиво и быстро.

Но вот **2** браузер ничего не отображает. Пока чисто. Я отправил такие сообщения так же, как и в предыдущем примере: 4 4, 5 5, 6 6. Все также хорошо работает, но вижу я только 3 последних сообщения, отправленных с этого браузера.

Если же перезагрузить страничку, отобразятся все сообщения: 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4 и т.д. по порядку, как должно быть.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы какой-то ajax-запрос или скрипт или что-то на подобии этого все время "слушало" изменения??? То есть если отправил с 1 браузера сообщение - оно тут же отобразилось и во втором. Как так сделать?

Код:

```js
var d = new Date();

var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();
var time;
var MyDate = new Date();
var MyDateString;

MyDate.setDate(MyDate.getDate() + 20);

MyDateString = ('0' + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('0' + (MyDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '.' + MyDate.getFullYear();
time = hours + ":" + minutes;

$(function() {
 $("#send").click(function(){
  if ($("#author").val() != ""){
   var author = $("#author").val() + ", " + MyDateString + ", " + time;
  }
  var message = $("#message").val();      
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "sendMessage.php",
   data: {"author": author, "message": message, },
   cache: false,      
   success: function(response){
    var messageResp = new Array('Message not sent','Message not sent, DB error',' You can not send blank messages');
    var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
    if(response == 0){
     $("#author").val("");
     $("#message").val("");
     
     $("#commentBlock").prepend("<table style='width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ccc;'><tr><td width='50px;' style='padding:5px;'> <img src='ava.jpg' width='50px' style='border-radius:50px;'> </td><td style='padding:5px;'> "+author+" </td></tr><tr><td colspan='2' style='padding:5px; padding-bottom:0;  overflow-wrap: break-word;  word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;  -webkit-hyphens: auto; -ms-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;'> "+message+" </td> </tr></table><br><br>");
    }
    $("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
    
   }
  });
  return false;
    
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="commentBlock">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` ORDER BY `id` DESC",$db);
$comment = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do{
if ($comment != ""){
echo " 
 <table style='width: 100%; border-radius: 5px;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ccc;'>
  <tr>
   <td width='50px;' style='padding:5px;'> <img src='ava.jpg' width='50px' style='border-radius:50px;'> </td>
   <td style='padding:5px;'> ".$comment['author']." </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td  colspan='2' style='padding:5px; padding-bottom:0;  overflow-wrap: break-word;  word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;  -webkit-hyphens: auto; -ms-hyphens: auto; hyphens: auto;'> ".$comment['message']." </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <br>
 <br>
";
}
} while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
</div>


<!-- sendMessage.php: -->
<?php 

include("connect.php");
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if(empty($_POST['js'])){
 if($_POST['message'] != '' && $_POST['author'] != ''){

  $author = @iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $_POST['author']);
  $author = addslashes($author);
  $author = htmlspecialchars($author);
  $author = stripslashes($author);
  $author = mysql_real_escape_string($author);
  
  $message = @iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8", $_POST['message']);
  $message = addslashes($message);
  $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
  $message = stripslashes($message);
  $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`author`, `message`) VALUES ('$author', '$message')");
  if($result == true){
   echo 0; 
  }else{
   echo 1; 
  }
 }else{
  echo 2; 
 }
}

if($_POST['js'] == 'no'){
 if($_POST['message'] != '' && $_POST['author'] != ''){

  $author = $_POST['author'];
  $author = addslashes($author);
  $author = htmlspecialchars($author);
  $author = stripslashes($author);
  $author = mysql_real_escape_string($author);
  
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $message = addslashes($message);
  $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
  $message = stripslashes($message);
  $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` (`author`, `message`) VALUES ('$author', '$message')");
  if($result == true){
   echo "Your message has been successfully sent";
  }else{
   echo "Message not sent, DB erro";
  }
 }else{
  echo "You can not send blank messages"; 
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Для чата также неплохо взять NodeJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте гениальные вебсокеты и забудьте про аякс. В данном варианте его в нынешнее время не используют для чата.
Вебсокеты позволяют из сервера уведомить браузер.
Только на php делать вебсокеты-это геморой

Comment: Так же советую автору вопроса присмотреться к centrifuge js.
Все очень просто и удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, текущая проблема довольна очевидно. Вы никаким образом не получаете новые сообщения, отправленные другими пользователя. Т.е. Ваш php код не присылает вам новые комменты через ajax.

Comment: Как же сделать так, чтобы php-код присылал новые комментарии через ajax?

Comment: Вам нужно, что называется следить за ними. Например каждые 5 секунд посылать запрос на получение новых (или можно всех) комментов

Comment: но лучше вебсокеты использовать для этих целей

Comment: Это не серьезный проект, а просто "для души". Хм.. То есть просто каждые 5 секунд выполнять php-скрипт, который используется для выведения на страницу всех сообщений? А нагрузка на процессор не большая будет? Потому что я раз экспериментировал с циклом, сделал ошибку и цикл стал бесконечным. За пару десятков секунд использование процессора хоста 99%/100%.

Comment: давайте свой код, посмотрим

Comment: Код добавил в тему. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Это тот код, который выводит сообщения в блок из БД.

Comment: Уберите do .. if (....) и на это место перенесите **while(...)**

Comment: Изменение типа цикла поможет?

Comment: Нет, а JS код прикрепите?

Comment: Добавил. После <!-- sendMessage.php: --> содержимое файла sendMessage.php.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64457/discussion-between-hinc-and--).

Comment: можете весь код скинуть?